# How to read { and ( from .ini configs file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

i have the below posted password, and it saved in `.ini`  config. file. the following characters are marked or highlighted in red: `(` and `{`
how can i be able to read them

here is how i created the `.ini` file:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configs.ini')
```

**configs.ini**:

```
CLIENT_SECRET = P^L|Tf5x&9_2TIStIM({IdN^hObZ/-v2{KB(3
```

Comment: Assuming this is an example password but still pointing out that any password that has been published can no longer be considered save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer. the encoding type should have been added to the reader as follows:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configs.ini', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add section name in your configs.ini file

please modify your code as below:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configs.ini')

client_secret = config.get('Client_details', 'CLIENT_SECRET')
print(client_secret)
```

configs.ini

```
[Client_details]
CLIENT_SECRET = P^L|Tf5x&9_2TIStIM({IdN^hObZ/-v2{KB(3
```